# require(...) is not a function

Tags: sockets, socket.io

i have started Socket.IO just now but i am unable to get it run properly. Hers is the code

app.js

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
   res.sendFile('index.html');
});

http.listen(3000, function(){
   console.log("Listening On Port *: 3000");
});
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Hello World</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        Hello World
    </body>
</html>
```

When i try to run it using node or nodemon, both have installed and i have socket.io installed globally (v1.7.3) it shows

```
TypeError: require(...) is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (I:\Bilal\Aptech\Tutorials Point Practice\Socket.IO\Chapter 1 - Hello World\app.js:1:91)
    at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:605:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:423:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:147:9)
    at bootstrap_node.js:538:3
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is because you try to call require as a function with `()` at the end. Try this:

`var app = require('express');`

Otherwise, try this:

`var express = require('express');
var app = express();`

Comment: after i tried what you said TypeError: app.get is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (I:\Bilal\Aptech\Tutorials Point Practice\Socket.IO\Chapter 1 - Hello World\app.js:4:5)
    at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:605:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:423:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:147:9)
    at bootstrap_node.js:538:3

Comment: see this : https://www.tutorialspoint.com/socket.io/socket.io_hello_world.htm. My code is same ...!

Comment: it worked! will mark it as answer soon :) Thanks alot :)

Comment: it also worked ! Thanks :) marking it as answer soon!

Comment: can anyone help me with this thing : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43633007/cant-find-module-angular2-core-and-angular2-platform-browser?noredirect=1#comment74320539_43633007

Comment: i have posted for the 2nd time but no response :(

Answer (score 0):

you probably do not have express installed, If it is not installed required('express') returns null which is not a function

to fix run

```
npm install express
```

Comment: i can run express node apps fine. I have every module installed globally and i have set NODE_PATH to node_modules

Comment: Could it be an old version of express? I just tryed your code on my system and it worked perfictly with express installed, also maybe try

    console.log( typeof require('express') );

That should show you what is being returned

Comment: i have updated my node_modules just before running it! :)